# My modal can not receive data from jquery script in Laravel

Tags: html, jquery, css, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have modal script like this:

```
<div class="modal" id="assignstore" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
.....some of code.....
        <div class="row mb-3">
           <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label  text-md-end">
              {{ __("Subject") }}
            </label>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                     <input id="title-as">
                 </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have data from here:

```html
<a href="#" 
    data-target="#assignstore" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-titleas="{{ $subject->title }}"
    data-idas="{{ $subject->id }}" 
    class="a btn btn-warning"
>
    Assignment 
</a>
```

This is my Jquery Script:

```
<script>
    $('#assignstore').on('show', function(e) {
        var link = e.relatedTarget(),
            modal = $(this),
            id = link.data("idas"),
            title = link.data("titleas");

        modal.find("#title-as").val(title);
        modal.find("#id-as").val(id);
    });
</script>
```

Could you help me to find out what's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0):

it **depends what error you receive**. btw here is some solutions (maybe it works for you) :

1. replace your script (make sure jquery runs before ur script)
2. change the way ur script fires
3. what is **$subject** on ur code? if it is an item of an array we should know what is this item (make sure u r calling items well)

Comment: thank you for your suggest. i did what you suggest, but still it doesn't work properly.
so i change to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pass-data-to-modal-dialog#best-reply-114445